# how to change the barchart values using slider in ios

Tags: ios, slider, uislider, bar-chart

I have a problem in my bar chart application in iOS. I created a barchart using [DSBarChart](http://dhilipsiva.com/DSBarChart/) and slider control. I want the chart to change dynamically when I change the slider. How do I do that? Here is a sample code of what I have doe so far.

```
- (void)sliderValueDidChange:(UISlider *)sender {
    if((int)slider.value % 10 == 0) {
        positionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)slider.value];
        myValue =  (int)slider.value;
    }

    NSDictionary *dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], @"0",
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:20], @"1",
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:15], @"2",
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:25], @"3",
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:30], @"4",
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:20], @"5",
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:15], @"6",
                         nil];

    DSBarChart *chrt = [[DSBarChart alloc] initWithFrame:ChartView.bounds
                        color:[UIColor greenColor]
                        andDictionary:dict];
    chrt.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    chrt.bounds = ChartView.bounds;
    [ChartView addSubview:chrt];
}
```

Comment: I don't know what mistake you are making, you should let us know what's the problem.

Comment: Hi, I created DSBarChart. What exactly are you trying to do here? Are you trying to have multiple sliders that maps to the chart? I dont understand your question clearly. If you could edit/comment more clearly, I'll help you.

Comment: Hi,Mr.DhilipSiva I want to create bar chart with slider control. when my slider change or moves my bar chart values are also change and my diagram also change. I don't know how to do?

Answer (score 0):

[DSBarChart](http://dhilipsiva.com/DSBarChart/) does not dynamically bind to controls, yet! But there is a work-around. When the value change of the slider is triggered, you can remove the exsisting DSBarchart instance from the view, create a new chart with the changed value and add it into the view again. Currently, DSBarChart is in pre-alpha state. It doesnt do much. I will extend the functionality when I find time.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is creating custom view over the barChart.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

if (lineView) {
    [lineView removeFromSuperview];

    NSSet *allTouchesSet = [event allTouches]; 
    NSArray *allTouches = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[allTouchesSet allObjects]];   
    int count = [allTouches count];

    if (count  == 1) {

        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        tapPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        NSLog(@"tapPoint: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(tapPoint));

        UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tapPoint.x, 0.0, 1, 320.0)];
        lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [parentView addSubview:lineView];


    }
}

}
```